# Borel vs measure for all Borel measures

Tags: measure-theory, fa.functional-analysis

Let X be locally compact and Hausdorff, and let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function.  Suppose that for all finite regular (positive) Borel measures $\mu$, we know that $f$ is $\mu$-measurable.  Does it follow that $f$ is Borel?  If not, what's a good counter-example?

Definitions: The Borel sigma-algebra is generated by the open sets.  So $f$ is Borel if $f^{-1}(U)$ is Borel for each open $U\subseteq\mathbb R$.

I think the definition of $\mu$-measurable is that for each open $U\subseteq\mathbb R$, we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is in the completed sigma-algebra for $\mu$.  That is, we can find Borel sets $A$ and $B$ with $A \subseteq f^{-1}(U) \subseteq B$ with $\mu(B\setminus A)=0$.

Remark: The "obvious" measures are the point mass measures, but then the completed sigma-algebra is $2^X$, so all functions are measurable!  So the question is, in some sense, whether $X$ supports "enough" finite regular Borel measures.

Vague motivation: This old paper of Barry Johnson: Separate continuity and measurability.
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 20 1969 420--422 see http://www.jstor.org/stable/2035668  But Barry's paper clearly gives me enough for what I want, so really this question is out of curiosity, not an attempt to understand the paper better!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be the characteristic function of a subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ which is analytic but not Borel. Then $f$ is universally measurable but not Borel.

Comment: Thanks, François. It's still too early in the morning ...

Comment: Brilliant!  I found some more details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_measurable

Answer (score 3):

The collection of Borel sets (or analytic sets, etc.) in $\mathbb{R}$ has power $c = 2^{\aleph_0}$.  But the collection of universally measurable sets has power $2^c$.  This would follow from the existence of a **universal null set** of power $c$.

Comment: The collection of Borel sets on $\mathbb{R}$ has this cardinality,
but not the collection of Borel sets on an arbitrary locally
compact $X$.

Comment: corrected to refer to R

Comment: Isn't the Borel Conjecture (which independent of ZFC) precisely the statement that every universally null set is countable?

Comment: No, the Borel Conjecture is the statement that every strong measure zero set is countable.

Comment: Aren't SMZ sets precisely the sets which are null with respect to every continuous Borel probability measure? Or am I misunderstanding "universal null set"?

Comment: The official definition of universally null set is given in 

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2002-130-12/S0002-9939-02-06465-1/S0002-9939-02-06465-1.pdf

where it points out there are uncountable examples in ZFC.

Comment: According to Wikipedia: "the Borel conjecture asserts that an aspherical closed manifold is determined by its fundamental group, up to homeomorphism."  ... a little humor there ... The Borel conjecture of concern here is about strong measure zero, which implies universal null, but is not equivalent.  Note Hausdorff constructed a universal null set of cardinal $\aleph_1$.  Is there one of power $c$?  I don't know, that is why I said "would follow" in my answer...


Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for the clarification! The paper that Simon linked says that Grzegorek gave an example of size non(null) (the smallest size of a non-measurable set). This is probably best possible?

Comment: So, to complete my education, why are there $2^c$ universally measurable sets? (Assuming the worst case scenario non(null) = $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_1} = 2^{\aleph_0}$.)

Comment: Actually it's consistent that there are only continuum many universally measurable sets. This is a recent result of Larson, Neeman and Shelah, see www.math.ucla.edu/~ineeman/UM.pdf 